# Why Use a Makefile instead of just writing C to do the same?

Tags: c, makefile

This question is **not** opinion-based - I am looking for *objective* drawbacks to the *easy* approach that I know may not be ideal, but seems quite alright *prima facie*.

**EDIT:** I do not mean to imply that in some way I am writing my *own* Make in C - no, I'm only wondering if, in simple and small programs, this sort of approach has any drawbacks over make.

Now, the question.

C is a general purpose, systems-programming oriented language, so it is safe to assume that one can hack-together anything with it.

Of course, we have different languages and tools allowing us to use the best tool *for the job*, and Makefiles are **specifically** for compiling efficiently and with least hassle - this I get.*But*, one can basically do with C what they do with a makefile - and apparently with no more difficulty !?

Apart from 'not using *industry standards*', what objective drawbacks does such an approach bring ?

A bad 2-minute sample, by no means perfect or finished, and without the file-selective compilation, but just to kind of illustrate my point -

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\n Mode : "); int mode; scanf("%d",&mode);

    if(mode==1){
        system("cc -Wall -o3 file1.c file2.c -o bin_file_name");
    }
    else if(mode==2){
        system("cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -o0 file1.c file2.c -o bin_file_name");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220966/discussion-on-question-by-user13863346-why-use-a-makefile-instead-of-just-writin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to the other answers - make is a tool specific to the task you are trying to do, C is far more general. Therefore it's far easier to do this in makefile. Let's take your simple C "make" example and convert to it to an equivalent makefile:

### C Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\n Mode : "); int mode; scanf("%d",&mode);

    if(mode==1){
        system("cc -Wall -o3 file1.c file2.c -o bin_file_name");
    }
    else if(mode==2){
        system("cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -o0 file1.c file2.c -o bin_file_name");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Makefile code

```
FLAGS = -Wall -o3
ifndef MODE2
  FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -o0
endif

bin_file_name:
    cc $(FLAGS) file1.c file2.c -o bin_file_name
```

The (or some) advantages are:

- It's simpler
- It does not need to be compiled
- Once bin_file_name is created it won't re-create it
- You get tab-completion for make targets

Then with a very simple tweak or two:

```
FLAGS = -Wall -o3
ifndef MODE2
  FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -o0
endif

bin_file_name: file1.c file2.c
    cc $(FLAGS) file1.c file2.c -o bin_file_name

clean:
    rm bin_file_name
```

Now bin_file_name has dependencies on the source file, so if you change any of them it will only re-compile when you run make if one of those deps have changed. You would need to start writing a lot more C code to achieve the same. There are a lot of makefile features (like string processing) that make it so much better for the job than writing C code.

Another way of thinking about it: it's a bit like asking why write a simple C program when you can write the same in assembler without too much effort :o

Comment: Thanks for your kind, clear and helpful answer ! I must say, you description in you profile could not be more wildly inaccurate !

Answer (score 3):

You could write a C program which efficiently builds a given project. This is what you shown code seems to imply.
For more complex projects that would of course be more complex.
Soon you would develop your program to do some analysis (e.g. dependencies) automatically, instead of hardcoding it each time.
Then you would discover, that from project to project, those analysis need to take different, project-specific, concepts and structures into account.
That would introduce the concept of project-specific configuration into your program.

At that point you would have reinvented the make tool, with its project-specific configuration done in files like makefiles.

Comment: I fail to see why complexity will increase so catastrophically if all OP has to do is make more if-else statements that send different commands to the shell. And arent makefiles project specific too ? There's no reinvention that OP is doing, he's just simplifying the commands to send to the shell .

Comment: @APJo I did not say "catastrophically". But if you have not seen projects which require much more effort for building AND maintenance, then I cannot imagine that you earn money as a programmer, project manager or system architect.

Comment: And yes, makefiles are project specific. That is more or less the point of my answer. I think I do not get your point. @APJo

Comment: No, no OP's code is a toy. I agree with you 100%, serious effort is needed in maintaining any real major project. However, OP has *clearly* stated that he's only talking of trivial projects, which is where I said it wont be too complex in his context

Comment: OP has after my answer added phrasings towards the "simple" end of the scale. I consider that an inappropriate moving target question.

Answer (score 2):

Your C program basically calls the shell to execute the compiler. In this, it's just a convoluted way to write a shell script.

A shell script would still unconditionally run the compiler. Even if the source file(s) remained untouched. Unless you write the timestamp tests yourself.

Running the compiler *only where necessary* is one of the core features of `make`. Providing a simple syntax to state which files are generated from / depending on which sources, and how to get from one to the other (simpler than writing the same in a shell script), is another. Doing so for *patterns* instead of specific file names is a third.

So in the end, the answer to this question is the same as the answer to "why don't we write all our apps in Assembler". It's about using the right abstraction level for the job, for efficiency, readability, and maintainability.

Your C program is more complicated than a shell script. A shell script is more complicated than a Makefile. We don't like complicated, we like easy.

And, to pick up a comment by @dxiv, if you wrote your C program to be as useful as `make`, doing the dependency checks, and perhaps reading the filenames to act upon from a configuration file instead of having them hardcoded... well, then you'd just have re-invented `make`.

Comment: Well, assembler is unportable ;) ... Ofc I'm kidding , I get the point

Comment: @user13863346: Oh... and never, **ever**, use `scanf()` without checking the return value. You might be using `mode` uninitialized there. ;-)

Comment: "*it's just a convoluted way to write a shell script*", not really . "*would still unconditionally run the compiler*" ... no ! more if-else cases can be trivially added to selectively compile one source file and link it with the rest , and all in little code(since he's just sending over commands to the shell) and OP will just have to enter a number .

Comment: @APJo ...then you'd have to leave the realm of standard C, because the standard doesn't allow you to determine a file's modification date. You'd end up with a custom make variant with still hardcoded file names. *And* your program would very quickly stop being "simpler" than make by any definition. Sure, you *can* do everything in assembler or raw binary. Doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Leave *the realm of standard C* Shock ! Horror ! No ! This fragile standard is all I have that protects me from the vicious world of incompatible  POSIX v/s WinAPI platforms...

Answer (score 2):

`make` does many things more than your toy example does. Here are just a few of the most common:

- It knows how to compile programs in lots of languages, and you can easily extend it with additional rules.
- It checks dependency relationships, so that it only recompiles the files that have changed, and then recompiles other programs that depend on those outputs.
- You can organize your project into groups of code, and specify which groups should be rebuilt.
- You can provide optional parameters, which will be substituted into the commands.

Getting all these details right is complex. Why would you want to spend time writing your own program to do these, when what you really want to work on is your application? And you would have to write a new one of these programs for every project.

Of course, each of these programs would be very similar. You would probably write a library of functions to handle the common tasks. Guess what -- your library would be doing what `make` already automates.

You can also do what `awk` and `sed` do by writing C programs. But the whole point of creating tools is that they automate tasks that lots of different people have to do the same way.

Comment: OP seems to have made it clear that these features are quite unnecessary to him, and further , he can basically do *anything* a terminal will allow him to (with much less typing) through this approach without writing much code since he can just send the command to the shell .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there's no compelling reason to use a Makefile to build "Hello World". The more complex an application becomes -- and in particular the more inter-dependent components it contains -- the harder it is to manage the build process without specific tools. Try to build a C application that consists of five thousand source files in twenty distinct libraries, and you'll soon appreciate the advantages of some kind of build tooling.

Sure, you could write that tooling yourself, in a language of your choice -- but why bother, when it already exists?

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] your posts? Please delete the very similar other answer.